# Stata: Difference in mean with Survey data

Tags: stata, survey

I am fairly new to Stata so some of my questions may be pretty basic, but I appreciate any help I can get. An example of my data is below

```
wage  surveyweights Constant Sex

32    14            .56      1
56    45            .96      1
77    88            .25      0
```

I have survey data and I am trying to bootstrap the difference in mean wages for **women ONLY**. I want to find out the difference in mean outcome with [survey weights] and with [survey weights * constant] that is **Manual calculation**

```
mean x [pw=wt] if sex==1
mat x1=e(b)
mean x [pw=wt*constant] if sex==1
mat x2= e(b)

mat dd=x1-x2

**my outcome of interest is the point estimate and bootstrapped SE of dd
```

I have written the following program, but I am not getting the results I want. In particular, my SE column turns up blank and my point estimates for the means and the difference in means do not match with what I get with manual calculation.

```
program define meandiff, eclass properties (svyb)
args vars

mean `vars' 
mat x1=e(b) 
mean `vars' [pw=constant] 
mat x2=e(b) 

mat dd = x1-x2
ereturn scalar dd=e1(dd,1,1)

end

local vars wage
svy bootstrap e(dd), subpop(sex): means `vars'
```

**I have already svyset my data using bootstrap weights**. My questions are as follows:

1. When I type svy: mean 'vars' the program seems to start running bootstrap replications, and when I type svy bootstrap: means `vars' also the program seems to start replications. What is the difference between the two commands?
2. When I do `mean x` with regular survey weights do I need to do `[pw=wt]` or will `svy` command automatically apply the survey weights?
3. If I do have to write `[pw=wt]` in the first mean then do I need to create a variable called, say,  `gen wtxcons = wt * constant` to do `[pw=wtxcons]` when I calculate the second mean?
4. How do I calculate the bootstrap SE and point estimates for my outcome of interest, which is the difference in means. Why are my point estimates not matching my manual calculation?

Comment: Subsequently posted on Statalist at [http://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1310427-difference-in-mean-with-survey-data](http://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1310427-difference-in-mean-with-survey-data).